# How to list all file mapping handles in Win32(64)?

Tags: winapi

How to list all the file mappings that were created/opened using CreateFileMapping()/OpenFileMapping?

Comment: Your own process or all processes in system?

Comment: That's forbidden knowledge in Windows, it requires accessing undocumented internal kernel structures.

Comment: What is the practical programming problem you are trying to solve? Maybe there's another way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far Manager plugin "ProcList" shows the list of handles. Look the source [handles.cpp](http://farmanager.com/svn/trunk/plugins/proclist/handles.cpp). You need to look at function

```
bool PrintHandleInfo(DWORD dwPID, HANDLE file, bool bIncludeUnnamed, PerfThread* pThread)
```

`DWORD dwPID` - inspecting PID,
`HANDLE file` - is a handle to output text file.